# JIRA home config

Tags: command-line, configuration, terminal, jira

I am having a few issues configuring JIRA (Mac OSX 10.6.8), specifically setting my JIRA home directory. I ran the JIRA configuration tool, and defined my path. Upon running JIRA on my localhost, I get the message: No jira.home is configured. Through my terminal, I went in to edit my jira-application.properties files, and it says jira.home = /Applications/MAMP/jira/htdocs. At this point, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, as it seems jira.home is defined. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Setting your JIRA Home Directory](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Setting+your+JIRA+Home+Directory) and make sure you are pointing to the Jira home folder:

```
Edit the jira-application.properties file and set the value of the 'jira.home' 
property to the desired location for your JIRA Home Directory. If you are specifying 
this location's path on Windows, use double back-slashes ("\") between subdirectories.
 For example, X:\\path\\to\\JIRA\‌\Home
```

To find where Jira home is located, have a look at [JIRA Installation Directory page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+Installation+Directory),  the folder should contain the logs,jss and plugins folders.

So, if for example the Jira is installed at *`/var/atlassian/application-data/jira`* , the 
*`jira-application.properties`* should have the following line:

```
jira.home = /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
```

**Please note** - Jira home directory is referring to a data directory and **not** the installation directory

Answer (score 0):

Installing Jira on MacOS:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA042/Installing+JIRA+Standalone+on+Mac+OS

NOTE: Setting your Home (aka data) directory to /Applications/MAMP/jira/htdocs means that your Jira installation is located in your MAMP web root... Are you sure that's where Jira is installed? Typically, on a Mac, the home directory is located here:
/Applications/Jira/HOME